# Why is this inheritance structure built like this?

Tags: python, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I've been struggling to understand the details of this code for a couple of days now:

```
class Rectangle:
    def __init__(self, length, width, **kwargs):
        self.length = length
        self.width = width
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def area(self):
        return self.length * self.width

    def perimeter(self):
        return 2 * self.length + 2 * self.width

# Square inherits from Rectangle:
class Square(Rectangle):
    def __init__(self, length, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(length=length, width=length, **kwargs)


# Triangle doesn't inherit from any class:
class Triangle:
    def __init__(self, base, height, **kwargs):
        self.base = base
        self.height = height
        super().__init__(**kwargs) 

    def tri_area(self):
        return 0.5 * self.base * self.height

# Pyramid inherits from square and triangle:
class Pyramid(Square, Triangle):
    def __init__(self, base, slant_height, **kwargs):
        self.base = base
        self.slant_height = slant_height
        
        # Adding attributes to kwargs dictionary
        kwargs["height"] = slant_height
        kwargs["length"] = base
        super().__init__( base=base, **kwargs)

    def area(self):
        base_area = super().area()
        perimeter = super().perimeter()
        return 0.5 * perimeter * self.slant_height + base_area

    def area_2(self):
        base_area = super().area()
        triangle_area = super().tri_area()
        return triangle_area * 4 + base_area
```

The inheritance tree is as such:

```
Rectangle 
    \
   Square  Triangle
      \     /
      Pyramid
```

The MRO for the `Pyramid` class:

```
(__main__.Pyramid,
 __main__.Square,
 __main__.Rectangle,
 __main__.Triangle,
 object)
```

I understand the general idea behind the code, and how `super().__init__` is used to pass a dictionary of variable keyword arguments to the superclass using `**kwargs`. The details I'm having issues with are:

1. Why did we, in the `Pyramid` class, use `base=base` when the superclass (`Square`) takes a `length` argument?
2. When I do only put `super().__init__(base, **kwargs)` instead of `base=base`, why does it give an error saying that ****init**() got multiple values for argument 'length',** is it because of the `kwargs["length"]` specified above it? If so, how does base=base solve that?
3. Why do we have `super().__init__(**kwargs)` in Rectangle when it doesn't have a superclass? My guess is maybe to pass the kwargs to the built-in `object` base class so `Triangle` can inherit from it? But I'm not sure.
4. Why would `Triangle` also have a call to the base class too? It seems redundant (even removing `super().__init__(**kwargs)` from Triangle doesn't change anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good questions!

1. Because `Square.__init__` accepts `**kwargs` we can actually pass whatever we want to it without getting an `unexpected keyword argument` error<sup>1</sup>. This will become handy a bit later. Any keyword argument that it (and/or its superclasses' `__init__` methods) does not consume will propagate up in the MRO until we get to `object`.

   <sup>1</sup>Usually. In this case the (unnecessery) call to

   `super().__init__(**kwargs)` in `Triangle.__init__` breaks this behavior.

2. Due to the expansion of `kwargs`, when calling `super().__init__(base, **kwargs)` in `Pyramid.__init__`, `Square.__init__` is actually called with  `(2, height=3, length=2)`. Since the argument of `Square.__init__` is called `length` you recieve the error about multiple values for `length`.
3. That's correct. Furthermore, because nothing "consumed" the `base` keyword argument yet, `Triangle.__init__` will receive it.
4. That's also correct. There is absolutely no need to call `super().__init__(**kwargs)` in `Triangle.__init__`, especially that by that point `kwargs` is an empty dict (all the keyword arguments it contained were consumed already).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed answer ! It cleared up a lot of things. I just wanted to know: 1) Why should it be exactly `base=base`? Because when I try to use only `base` or `length` I get an error. What's special about `base=base`. And 2) when you say the arguments get consumed, does that consumption happen by default whenever a method uses that kwarg or does it only happen when that kwarg is used also as a positional argument (because I've read that doing this "pops" the keyword argument out of the dictionary). Thanks !

Comment: @Metrician 1. `base=base` (or `whatever=base`) causes the value that `base` contains to be passed as a keyword argument (inside the `kwargs` dict)`. Without specifying it, it will be passed as the `location` positional argument which will cause a conflict (because `location` is already specified in the `kwargs` dict (point 2 in the answer).

Comment: @Metrician 2. When a method receives a `kwargs` dict that contains a key with the same name as one of its arguments, that argument (key-value pair in this context) is removed from the `kwargs` dict. You can clarify this by adding `print(kwargs)` throughout the `__init__` methods in the example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to respond it's all clear now ! Ridded me of a 2-day headache. Much appreciated.